# How can I combine two similar columns in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau Public to read data from a '|' separated text file. The goal is to determine how much damage each player dealt versus received. Currently the data only shows rows for each attacker. How can I change the data so that I see a row for each player?

Sample Source:

```
Attacker Name | Attacker Nation | Defender Name | Defender Nation | Attacking Damage | Defending Damage
Bob | Builder | Felix | Fixer | 100 | 120
Bob | Builder | Ralph | Wrecker | 150 | 75
Felix | Fixer | Ralph | Wrecker | 125 | 150
```

Desired Output:

```
Name | Nation | Opponent Name | Opponent Nation | Damage Dealt | Damage Received
Bob | Builder | Felix | Fixer | 100 | 120
Bob | Builder | Ralph | Wrecker | 150 | 75
Felix | Fixer | Bob | Builder | 120 | 100
Felix | Fixer | Ralph | Wrecker | 125 | 150
Ralph | Wrecker | Bob | Builder | 75 | 150
Ralph | Wrecker | Felix | Fixer | 150 | 125
```

Comment: you want to create 6 rows from 3 rows source?

Comment: I'm not sure about Tablea Public, bu in Desktop you could select the Attacker Name and Defender Name and pivot the data which would get you one step closer to what you wanted.